# mysql trigger update set null value instead of intended number

Tags: mysql, triggers, null

I'm trying to create mysql trigger which should take new inserted numbers from one table (raw_us), compare it to last record (is the new value higher than last one, or lower then last one), index them by ranges into values -10 to 10 and place into another table (indexed_us). My database tables:

```
 CREATE TABLE raw_us(rdate DATE,pmi DECIMAL(3,2));
 CREATE TABLE indexed_us(idate DATE, ipmi DECIMAL (2,2));
 INSERT INTO raw_us(rdate,pmi) VALUES(20000101, 50);
 INSERT INTO indexed_us(idate,ipmi) VALUES(20000101, 5);
```

I wrote the trigger code to sort out new raw data (inserted into table raw_us column pmi) - is new 'pmi' value bigger or smaller than last one, and then check what range the new raw data belongs, and then according to particular range insert the particular number into indexed_us table impi column. Here is my trigger code:

```
 DELIMITER //
 CREATE TRIGGER ipmiUS BEFORE INSERT ON raw_us
 FOR EACH ROW
 BEGIN
 DECLARE @old_pmi int;
 SET @old_pmi = (select pmi from raw_us where rdate = MAX(rdate));
 IF (@old_pmi < NEW.pmi) THEN
   IF (50 < NEW.pmi) AND (NEW.pmi < 60)
     THEN INSERT INTO indexed_us(idate,ipmi) VALUES (new.date,6);
   ELSEIF (60 < NEW.pmi) AND (NEW.pmi < 70)
     THEN INSERT INTO indexed_us(idate,ipmi) VALUES (new.date,7);
   END IF;
 ELSEIF (@old_pmi > NEW.pmi) THEN
   IF (50 > NEW.pmi) AND (NEW.pmi > 60)
     THEN INSERT INTO indexed_us(idate,ipmi) VALUES (new.date,5);
   ELSEIF (40 > NEW.pmi) AND (NEW.pmi > 50)
     THEN INSERT INTO indexed_us(idate,ipmi) VALUES (new.date,4);
   END IF;
 END IF;
END; //
DELIMITER ;
```

And the problem is that after updating trigger to 'BEFORE INSERT' and fixing within ranges IF statements to  ' IF (number > NEW.pmi) AND (NEW.pmi > number) ' I just get error:
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER // CREATE TRIGGER ipmiUS BEFORE INSERT ON raw_us FOR EACH ROW ' at line 1.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understood you correctly, but an `after update`-trigger does not execute when you do an `insert`. It executes when you do an `update`. You are maybe looking for an `after insert`-trigger? I am also not entirely sure why you use 2 triggers for this, you might simply insert your complete row in that one `after insert` trigger (but then again, we don't know what your first trigger does).

Comment: Thank you Solarflare. I think you are right and thats the reason it set NULL value. But in case I use 'AFTER INSERT' trigger I cant compare 'last' and 'new' records. This mean I have to compose all new trigger?

Comment: For an insert, there is no `old`. It is not entirely clear what you are trying to compare a completely new row with. If you need your logic both for inserts and updates, you have to write a trigger for insert and one for update. You should probably add your other trigger though so we understand what you are doing. I would assume you can use one trigger for `insert` that does everything (including setting the values 4 to 6) when you insert a row, and one for `update` that does what needs to be done for an `update`. You should also fix the comparisons as mentioned in joanolos answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You most probably have a problem with the `IF` expressions. You are writing your "within range" `(30 < NEW.pmi < 40)` in a way that doesn't produce the intended results.

To make it clear, just try this:

```
SELECT
    30 < 1 < 40 ;
```

You get as a response:

```
| 30 < 1 < 40 |
| ----------: |
|           1 |
```

This is because MySQL is actually computing:

```
SELECT
    (30 < 1) < 40 ;
```

The result of `(30 < 1)` is `false`, and represented by MySQL as a `0`, then `(0 < 40)` is `true`, and represented as a `1`.

You need to rewrite your conditions like this:

```
IF (30 < NEW.pmi) AND (NEW.pmi < 40) THEN
    -- whatever
...
```

Also, take into account that you have some corner cases *not* being taken into account. For instance, when `40 = NEW.pmi`, you probably want *something to happen*. When checking ranges, it is a good practice to have comparisons like:

```
`(lower_bound <= value) AND (value < upper_bound)`
```

(Note `<=` and `<`).

Note also, you can write (*note both <= and <=*)

`(lower_bound <= value) AND (value <= upper_bound)`

with the equivalent form

```
value BETWEEN lower_bound AND upper_bound
```

This is only a good practice when you deal with `INTEGER`s or `DECIMAL`s, but *not* if you use `FLOAT`s.

---

See the whole example at *dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=8ab9e2aaba0844e74059a12ccbd2dd24)*

Comment: Thank you Joanolo. I underatstand now that 'within range' statements are wrong. I will fix this. Purpose of the trigger is to generate index numbers from raw data  inserted into raw table and write those numbers into indexed table. Basically I have ranges and particular values should be written into indexed table according to particular ranges of raw data. I just need one more condition which is to compare latest record in raw data to new record in raw data to identify is the new number increasing or decreasing. I hope my weak english helps. Thank you for patiens reading my reply.